# Detect click and get text of QTableWidget header, how?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I see how to detect click in a `QTableWidget` cell by watching the `cellClicked(int row, int column)` signal (code below).

I would like to do the same for the cells of the horizontal header and get the text of the clicked header cell. How do I do that?

```
// mainwindow.h
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    QWidget widget;
    QVBoxLayout vLayout {&widget};
    QStringList headers {"asdca", "asdcad", "asdcadca"};
    QTableWidget table {5, headers.size()};
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow() {}
};

// mainwindow.cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    setCentralWidget(&widget);
    vLayout.addWidget(&table);
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
    connect(&table, &QTableWidget::clicked, []{
       qDebug() << "click!!" ;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
auto header = table->horizontalHeader();
connect(header, &QHeaderView::sectionClicked, [this](int logicalIndex){
    QString text = table.horizontalHeaderItem(logicalIndex)->text();
   qDebug() << logicalIndex << text;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get [QHeaderView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html) for you `QTableWidget`with method [horizontalHeader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader). `QHeaderView` have signal [sectionClicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionClicked). You can use it to determine text of the header item.